# Problema con iFrame en React al usarlo para mostrar una app hecha en flutter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flutter, iframe

Tengo una app en React que utiliza un iFrame para mostrar otra app hecha en flutter (ver 1era imagen):
[image: App en react]

La app hecha en flutter esta hosteada en un dominio (osea es un microfrontend). La app en React es un dashboard y esta hosteada en otro dominio diferente al de la app hecha en flutter.

Mi problema es que cuando prueba la app hecha en flutter directamente entrando al dominio en el cual esta hosteada, la app por si solo funciona tal cual se espera.
Cuando das click en el nombre de una persona, se abre un sidebar con informacion y un boton que dice "Gestion oferta".
[image: Sidebar]

Cuando doy click en el boton, me debe llevar a esta otra vista:
[image: visor]

Esto funciona como se espera, como lo mencione, directamente probando en la URL donde esta hosteada la app de flutter, pero al momento de hacerlo desde la app de react, no se comporta de esta forma si no que, al dar click en el boton, el iFrame me "clona"/muestra otra instancia de la misma app de React (dashboard), tal como se ve en la siguiente imagen:
[image: clonado]

Aqui esta el codigo de mi componente en la app de React que utiliza el iFrame para consumir/mostrar la app hecha en flutter:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { css } from '@emotion/react'
import Head from "next/head";
import DashboardLayout from "../../../layouts/DashboardLayout";
import { getTenantByCompanySiap } from "../../../helpers/tentant";
import { UAT, PROD, getEnv } from "../../../helpers/env";
export { getSSProps as getServerSideProps } from '../../../lib/Page'

export default function NuevaSolicitudPage(props) {

    const tenant = getTenantByCompanySiap(props.infoRh?.codeCompanySIAP)
    const branch = props.infoRh?.codeBranch
    const user = props.employeeData?.email

    const getCampanas = () => {
        const env = getEnv();
    
        const url = {
        [UAT]: `https://url-para-pruebas`,
        [PROD]: `https://url-para-produccion`
        };
    
        return url[env] || url[UAT];
    };

    const url = getCampanas()

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>Gestión de cartera | Campañas</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <DashboardLayout 
                {...props}
                title="Campanas"
            >
                <iframe
                src={url}
                css={css`
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                `}
                frameBorder="0"
                />
            </DashboardLayout>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

No tengo acceso al codigo de la app hecha en flutter, yo solo la consumo/muestro en el iFrame, pero escuche de alguien que tenia que configurar algunos archivos para poder mostrar aplicaciones hechas en flutter en un iFrame dentro de una app de react, pero ese alguien tampoco esta muy seguro. He buscado en internet algo sobre este problema especifico pero no he podido encontrar nada de utilidad ya que la app se muestra (al menos una parte bien) pero no se comporta bien como si lo hace dentro de su propia url.
Alguien podria darme una mano para saber como solucionar este problema? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sugiero intentar primero con las propiedades [referrerPolicy y sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-referrerpolicy) y sus diferentes configuraciones.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he probado tus sugerencias y ninguna me ayudo con el problema que tengo.